# HTML Pattern numbers and optional - symbol

Tags: html, regex

First question on this forum.
Im trying to make a HTML pattern that requiers numbers (length 1 to 20), and its optional to add a -.

so it should approve 040-123456 and 040123456.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Only problem that I dont know how to do is make a symbol optional. What I have tried is only basic stuff.

Comment: You should show us such basic stuff ([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).. anyway how many `-` are allowed in the pattern? and are they allowed in any position or only at a certain position?

Comment: They are allowed in any position.
so like 040-123456 or 0400-123546 should all be possible

Comment: But how many dashes are allowed? One or more? And the total length (1 to 20) should include also dashes or not?

Comment: I have fooled around on this site a bit, http://www.html5pattern.com/. but I just cant figure out how I make a pattern like that, I have never done it before. just tried like [0-9]{1,20}[-] but these didn't work, so pretty basic just fooling around.

Comment: yes only 1 dash, and that is included in the 20 characters, so 1 to 20 characters including 1 optional dash on any position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?=^\d*\-?\d*$)[\d\-]{1,20}
```

## Explanation

- (?=^\d*-?\d*$): Looks if the string is only composed by digits and one optional dash
- [\d-]{1,20}: Looks for a string with only digits and dashes, from one to twenty characters